# Applying update query on a record of 100,000 users on cassandra table using nodejs. Busy Connection issue

Tags: node.js, cassandra, es6-promise

I'm working with cassandra 3.x and node 10.13.0. I've data of 100,000 users in my working memory (in a map 'sortedRowMap' as in given code). I'm updating all of the record by iterating the map (having record of 100,000) users using for each. But it's throwing me BusyConnectionError. I'm wondering how could I get out from this.

Below is the implemented code of the aforementioned description.

```
var cassClient = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['localhost'],pooling: {
    coreConnectionsPerHost: {
        [distance.local] : 2,
        [distance.remote] : 1
    },
}, keyspace: 'xyz',
    socketOptions: { readTimeout: 65000 }
});

rank = 0;

for (const [msisdn, totalearnings] of sortedRowMap) {

     let updateRankQuery = "UPDATE users SET weeklyrank = " + rank + " WHERE 
     msisdn = " + msisdn;

     cassClient.execute(updateRankQuery, function (error, result) {
            if(!error){
                rank++;
                console.log("updateQuery: " + updateRankQuery)

            }else{
                console.log("ERROR: " + error)
            }
        })

}
```

and its throwing me this error:

ERROR: NoHostAvailableError: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: BusyConnectionError: All connections to host 127.0.0.1:9042 are busy, 2048 requests are in-flight on each connection. See innerErrors.

Comment: You have to apply some level of concurrency control to your application, it's not a good idea to launch 100,000 parallel operations. You can look at http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html or async `eachLimit`: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the number of in-flight requests per connection. Protocol version 3+ support up to 32k in-flight requests. You need to add corresponding option ([maxRequestsPerConnection](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.0/features/connection-pooling/#simultaneous-requests-per-connection)) into `pooling` object, like, this:

```
pooling: {
    coreConnectionsPerHost: {
        [distance.local] : 2,
        [distance.remote] : 1
    },
    maxRequestsPerConnection: 32768
}
```

But you can still hit this exception if all your requests are hitting the same nodes. In this case you'll need to throttle your submissions, or re-try them

Also see corresponding [section in DataStax Development Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/appDevGuide/driversConnectionPooling.html).

Comment: Whoooo... Thank you sooooo much sir. :) That is some great kick for me. Many thanks again :) Really appreciate your kind assistance.

Comment: Hi, my record increased so this (32778) requests isn't sufficient for now, is there any way I can do unlimited requested per connection? or is there anyway I can update my records?

Below is my code for making a connection.

Comment: let  DBconnection = {client: new cassandra.Client(
    {
        contactPoints: ['localhost'], pooling: {
        coreConnectionsPerHost: {
            [distance.local]: 2,
            [distance.remote]: 1
        },
        maxRequestsPerConnection: 32768
    }, keyspace: Constants.DATABASE_NAME.substring(0, Constants.DATABASE_NAME.length-1),
        socketOptions: {readTimeout: 120000}
    }
)};

Comment: You can't have unlimited number of in-flight requests - it's a limitation of the protocol. But frankly speaking - having too many in-flight request is sign that you're sending data much faster than your cluster can process - increasing it won't help. Our developers recommend not to have more than 1-2 thousand in-flight requests, otherwise you'll overload your cluster. Also, having too many in-flight request could be a sign of the problem with data model - if data isn't distributed well between nodes

Comment: so what do you recommend should I do to update approx 100,000 or even more than that records in database in a go (or it may take 1-2 minutes but it should update all of the rows)? is there any luck for me?

Comment: there are multiple ways: 1) if you have updates inside the same partition - you can batch them into unlogged batches - then the several updates will be still treated as one request. 2) split your data into several chunks (10-20 thousand each) and process chunk by chunk waiting until all request in chunks finished. 3) implement something like counting semaphore that increases on submitting new request, and decreasing when it's finished, and submit new request only if its value is lower than some threshold