# Bulk insert in not working in Casssandra with node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-node-driver

I am trying to insert more than 100 records using `batch()` method.

```
client.batch(batchQuery, { prepare: true }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ msg: err });
    } else {
        res.json([result.rows][0]);
    }
});
```

batchQuery has more than 100 insert queries. It is working if the records are less than 7. If its more than 10, then i am getting "Batch too large"

Comment: instead of the number of queries, you need to look into the size. Please check the cassandra logs and it will show the ERROR with the size and you can see the actual size

Comment: what kind of batch are you using (logged/unlogged)?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use batches for bulk inserts into Cassandra (in contrast to RDBMS) - this error that you get mean that you're inserting data into different partitions, and it pushes an additional load on the node that receives query.  You need to use batches only if you're doing inserts into the same partition - in this case they will be applied as a single mutation.

Otherwise, sending individual insert queries via async execute, will be much faster. You only need not to send too many requests at the same time (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301968/applying-update-query-on-a-record-of-100-000-users-on-cassandra-table-using-node/54312810#54312810)).

You can read more about good & bad use of batches in the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchTOC.html) and following answer on SO: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548450/executing-a-logged-batch-warning-in-cassandra-logs/54549308#54549308).